# Water dripping past gutters

Tags: roofing, gutters

I have one side of my gutter dripping below the overhang. I am attaching the photos of left and right side of the roof as well as the left from underneath where its dripping. Do you think the water is getting in through that small gap shown with green arrows? Could this also be amplified by the shingles not protruding more past the roof? How do I fix it?

Thanks!
David

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That looks to be a lot of water dripping through that small slit, unless you took that picture during a huge downpour, and the view towards the other building and trees doesn't indicate a downpour was in progress at the time the picture was taken.  The first thing I'd check is to confirm your downspouts are clear and the gutter isn't filling up and spilling over the backside.  Take a hose up there and see what happens when you put water into the gutter and make sure it drains well.

If the top of the downspout looks clear and you only have one downspout and there isn't anything obvious blocking it from the top, put an old towel into the top of the downspout to temporarily clog it up, and fill the gutter with water from a hose.  Then take the towel out and confirm the gutter empties quickly.  If not, you likely have a blockage that is further down your downspout.

How long is that gutter run?  There needs to be a slope to the gutter so it will drain.  If it's a really long piece of gutter it's hard to get it sloped properly all the way from end to end, and so the low end will tend to have issues like this if the drip edge isn't very high.  If this is the case, you could take thin sheets of strip metal and shove up underneath your drip edge to force the water down into the gutter rather than running behind the gutter.

Comment: The gutter is clear, good slope. Yes, a single downspout but doesn't fill up very often unless there is a serious downpour like you said. I do intend to expand this to 4x3 but it's on my "to-do" list - definitely not the issue this time.

I also think it is the gap, as it is more prominent on the downspout size and could have been caused by the gutter pulling down with weight from being clogged. I also wonder if the shingles aren't protruding long enough on this side and that causes water to return back up and run down that gap- I've seen pretty good overhang on other roofs.

Comment: At any rate, how do I eliminate this gap? Doubt something like silicone is an option here, or is it? Do I need to take the gutter down and resecure with new fasteners in different spots to make it rise up a bit?

Comment: I might be tempted to experiment and stick a long sheet of stiff plastic between the gutter and fascia from underneath, just to confirm that water isn't going over the gutter, underneath, and below the fascia (where you see it actively dripping in your last photo).

Comment: If it is getting through the gap with the green arrows, taking another piece of drip edge and pushing it up this gap a couple inches and having the hemmed edge lower in the gutter would eliminate the problem.  I'd just cut pieces and jamb them up between the gutter supports if that is the issue.  Taking the whole thing apart is a lot of  work.

Answer (score -1):

The overhang of the shingles is correct.

It looks as if your gutters are installed incorrectly.

The inner edge if the gutter (toward the facia) should be slipped under the drip edge.  Thereby having water from the roof drip into the gutter with no way to get between the back of the gutter and the facia.  Water in the gutter would get to that seam between the drip edge and gutter only if the drain is clogged or in the event of a horrendous deluge.

The screws holding the gutter should have the anchor points predrilled just into the facia board and polyester caulk should be dabbed into the holes prior to anchoring the screws.  This seals the screws from allowing water to seep between the threads and into the wood causing rot.  I know this is takes more time and expense, but it is the difference between a decade of good performance and a few years before all has to be ripped out and replaced.  (spend some now or pay more later.)

Another alternative is to eliminate the gutters altogether.  If you don't have a basement the rain water does not have to be diverted away from a foundation. Often proper grading is all that is needed along with some plantings that would like the showers.

Update:  After looking at the pics closely it is evident that whoever installed the gutter did not know what they were doing.
The anchors were bent for some reason.  This is a further indication that someone did a hack job and now the OP has issues. Here is the original design of the anchors [Box anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Amerimax-Aluminum-Gutter-Hidden-Hanger/3032886?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-bdm-_-ggl-_-LIA_BDM_103_Roofing-Gutters-_-3032886-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwhJukBhBPEiwAniIcNbOT_sFINTC7dsia-FS6rLiXkAqS84IZfGOvxQn2PjC2bl195wy4LRoCRBYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Others have suggested metal or plastic between the drip edge and the gutter.  This can work, but now will be difficult and result in cut fingers and coarse language.

The best action would be removing the gutter and reinstalling properly with the proper un-modified anchors.

Trying to blame the overhang of the shingles is like blaming the tree for being there when your car hit it.

Comment: Even without a basement, gutters are still a good idea, because they minimize erosion at the drip line.

Comment: @Huesmann,  that's the reason for the plants. To disperse the rain droplets and prevent erosion.  I had no gutters around my home for decades, never a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, sounds like the gutter needs to be reinstalled properly. So if the anchors are just attached to the fascia, I should be able to seal the old holes and start from scratch, correct? Any tips on attaching new anchors?

I do want to keep gutters here. Yes, there is a basement below, and also it is my front porch and while the slab it's sitting on is pretty high, I feel like it will create a lot of water problems (and I do have plants). Also, it is convenient when it is raining not too heavily to walk under the porch without the water draining on me.

Comment: Oh, not trying to blame overhang or anything at all. Just providing some basic facts, in case it is not obvious from the photos. Sounds like the gutter is sagging at the base like you suggested. Now just need to research how to reinstall the gutter properly.